# C programming: Delete string before first space

Tags: c

I want to enter a string and delete everything before first "space".

Here's an example:

Before

`Hello world`

After

`world`

Comment: what have you tried so far? Show your code! Do you think that we will write it for you? Hint: use `strchr` to find the space, then if found `strcpy`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This code should work for you. It makes use of the fact, that `str` is a pointer to the first character of the string.

```
char *str = "Hello world";
/*
 * Uncomment if `str` could be `NULL`:
 *
 * if (str == NULL) {
 *     fprintf(stderr, "Error: invalid string\n");
 *     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 * }
 */
while (*str != ' ' && *str != '\0') {
    ++str;
}
if (*str == ' ')
    ++str;
```

If you are not very familiar with pointers, this is a similar approach that might be easier to understand.

```
char *str = "Hello world";
/*
 * Uncomment if `str` could be `NULL`:
 *
 * if (str == NULL) {
 *     fprintf(stderr, "Error: invalid string\n");
 *     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 * }
 */
int i = 0;
while (str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\0') {
    ++i;
}
if (str[0] == ' ')
    str = &str[i + 1];
```

Comment: Yep that worked, I obviously need to practice pointers more

Comment: @Nikola Actually there were mistakes in the code. I have now updated my answer.

Comment: @Nikola If you are not very familiar with pointers, I have now added a second approach to my answer that might be easier to understand.

Comment: your code is incorrect

Comment: it will set the pointer to reference the character **past** the null character (in this case outside the string literal bounds) if the space was not found, which is UB

Comment: Try with str = "helloworld"

Comment: @AndySukowski-Bang it is very "naive" way of writing the code assuming that everything is OK. The main problem in programming are "corner cases" and the code has to handle it properly

Comment: @0___________ You are absolutely right! I have now updated my answer to implement your suggested change.

Comment: @AndySukowski-Bang what if str will be NULL? char *str = NULL; that is another corner case

Answer (score 1):

To cover corner cases you need to do some checks. It will return NULL if the pointer passed is NULL or the character was not found in the string.

```
char *getstrafter(const char *str, char c)
{
    if(str)
    {
        while(*str)
        {
            if(*str == c) break;
        }
    }
    return (char *)((str && !*str) ? NULL : str + 1);
}

char *getstrafter1(const char *str, char c)
{
    if(str)
    {
        str = strchr(str, c);
        if(str) str++;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: This checks `str == NULL` twice